# How to authenticate with REST API service on IIS using pass-through authentication in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, iis, ntlm-authentication

I need to send REST request to a REST API service, which is running on on-premiese IIS.
The IIS uses NTLM authentication, so I tried to send GET request using requests and requests_ntlm library, but the RESR API service does not function with IWA.

I tried to send a request using requests and requests_ntlm library with Windows username and password, but I got status code 401.
I would like to know how to authenticate with this REST APOI service using pass-through authentiction.

Comment: It’s just a poor design choice made. NTLM does not support any hops, and you have nothing to pass on. Kerberos is just too complicated to set up. Can you switch to a modern method like  OAuth and just pass on access tokens?

Comment: The REST API server is an old version of commercial product, which was released in 2019, and my customer does not want to change authentiction, due to their security policy.

Comment: Then your choice of using Python in the middle is your next challenge. How to configure Python to achieve AD based Kerberos delegation is not a well known topic, but you might dig further with search engines. Overall this is not a good question here, as giving you tutorials is off topic.

Comment: Integrated Windows Authentication (IWA) is a common method for enabling pass-through authentication with IIS. If NTLM authentication continues to pose issues, consider using Kerberos authentication instead. Kerberos is often preferred for pass-through authentication in Windows environments.